# Jsp file and Java Servlet is not updated after changes in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, servlets, browser

it may seems dublicate but i tried old posts about this problem and still can not solve...

with Eclipse Juno and Tomcat 7 , i develop dynamic web application in Eclipse . i have 2 Java Servlet under some packages , in first one i set some attributes to request and forward it to second Servlet with RequestDispacter and print this attribute in second Servlet with out.println....

when i change request or session attribute and forward to second one . page is not updated .

i restart tomcat or restart eclipse nothing changed..  i publish tomcat with Ctrl + Alt + P everytime but nothing changed ... i try external browser (Firefox and Internet Explorer) and delete caches but nothing changed ..

in Tomcat Server "Auto publish when resources changed" is enabled but nothing changed.

i try to Eclipse Luna and Tomcat 8 but it is has same problem . i did everything again but , still page is not updated !!  how to make it updated when change something in code..

i am in stuck now , any advice would be great ...

Comment: i think there is some cache clearance problems with local web browser of eclipse Use external web browser

Answer (score 4):

Make sure **Project>Build Automatically** is enabled.
Also try Tomcat>Clean...

Comment: yes i enabled "Build Automatically" and it seems solved . thank you

Answer (score 1):

Open problem section to see if you have anybuild problems.

Also try to build the project by clean project.

Answer (score 1):

1. Project>Build automatically should be enabled.
2. Project>Clean